# Facebook Share button with static image

Tags: facebook, share

I've set up a WordPress blog of mine and added a Facebook share button at the right sidebar, it's working but not showing the thumbnail image. I want to show only my default image as a thumbnail instead of my featured images. How can I set up a static (only my logo) thumbnail image for the share button ? I can see the 
meta og:image tag and it varies with articles but I want only my logo to be posted. Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance. Here is the url of my site- http://heera.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I lint your site: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fheera.it

It shows that you have coded the og meta tags correctly.

Currently your `og:image` set to `http://heera.it/wp-content/themes/shadows/images/hit.png`

If you want to change this, change the meta tag's content parameter to something else.

Here's what the complete meta tag currently looks like:

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://heera.it/wp-content/themes/shadows/images/hit.png" />`

**Update:**

Actually the problem was image itself. Everything was fine but the image was smaller than `200px` and Facebook didn't allow it. So increasing of the size of `og` image to `200px` the image would be showed up.

> All the images referenced by `og:image must` be at least 200px in both
>   dimensions.

[**Another ansower on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200312/what-is-the-minimum-width-and-height-of-facebook-open-graph-images).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that and I used lint too but I want to use this image to be used with share button always but it doesn't show the image at all and when I navigate to any particular article (using single.php), it uses the featured image and it's logically right but I always want to use my logo only with share button. Can you advise what to do. Thanks again!

Comment: What is a URL to one of your single.php pages you have a question about?  What does it lint to? What are the og tags being served down for that single.php?

Comment: I think you are confused. Basically og image changes with pages and articles. When I go to e.g. article one, og image uses article one's featured image, when I open e.g. article two, og image uses article two's featured image but I want for my share button to use only one image always not the og image that changes by pages/articles. How can I tell the share button to use hit.png (my logo) always. Hope it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: The og tag controls what image the like/send button will use to share.  You will need to change the og:image tag on each single.php page to be the hit.png.

Comment: But if I change this in each time in single.php then my featured image wont be published with other sharing widgets. Actually I have a global share button which is at the top of the page and I want to use this button to share my root url http://heera.it from any page/article and it does so but it doesn't use one static image. Can I set a static image only for one share button (it should not use the og image) and og image for other buttons. Thanks.

Comment: That's totally confusing.  The image to be used is specified in the HTML gotten from the URL being shared.  And that's the only way it is done.  If you have five like buttons on one page, each pointing to a different url to be liked, then the corresponding og tag of the url being shared is used, not the og tag in the page that displayed the 5 like buttons.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm taking your too precious time. Ok, please do it for me. Go to my site at http://heera.it and click at the topmost article and when it's loaded in your browser you do two things. At first share it (no need to share just click to see the result) by clicking the top share button (Share Heera.it on facebook), you'll see no image and then scroll down and click the facebook icon from the list (sharing is caring) and you'll get the point what I am trying to achiev. I want the top share button to share only my logo, a fixed image. Thanks for your time and I won't ask you again.

Comment: People are stack overflow are not getting paid to be here. We do this on our own free time.  Your share for heera.it is using a deprecated sharer.php and may be the source of your issues. Try using the social like plugin instead as it will correctly read the og meta tags.  The sharing is caring is not a facebook made plugin, however it too isn't using the sharer.php which is deprecated now.  It is showing the images correctly from the url that is being shared (http://heera.it/show-vipers-video-excerpt).

Comment: I've got my solution. The problem was the image itself, size was to small and Facebook doesn't allow that, even Google's plus one button was not working properly but everything is now fine. Now share and plus one both have fixed images (my logo) even when on the single.php and other buttons use featured image. thanks, anyway!

Comment: I've learned something new.  I knew that images can be too large, but not too small.  Good stuff!

Comment: I'm so glad I found this!  I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out why the image wasn't showing, and it was indeed because it was smaller than 200x200px.  (Oddly enough, it doesn't show in the facebook popup, but it DOES show in the actual facebook newsfeed. No matter, upping the dimensions fixed it.)