# how to upload image with feed using FB.api method

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

we are using `Fb API` for post feed on facebook.

my code is -

> ```
>             if (response.authResponse) {                   
>                 var data =
>                 {
>                     name: "link to apply",
>                     picture: 'http://www.hrgp.biz/Uploads/CompanyForTesting_499/NotesReminders/2608chemtec-logo.jpg',
>                     link: "http://www.hrgp.biz/bc0efdb3-f1a7-4d81-9635-d1418e808b6d.aspx",  // Go here if user click the picture
>                     description: "thank you"                        
>                 }
>                 FB.api('me/feed', 'post', data, function (response) {
>                     if (!response || response.error) {
>                         alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
>                     } else {
>                         //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
>                         alert('feed posted successfully.');
>                     }
>                 });                   
>             }
>         }, { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,photo_upload' });
> ```

This code Works but I’m having issues with the picture. It doesn’t show up in the post.

how can i resolve this issue? 
or 
     please tell me if any problem into my code.

thank you..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [What is the minimum width and height Of Facebook Open Graph Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200312/what-is-the-minimum-width-and-height-of-facebook-open-graph-images).

> The ratio of both height divided by width and width divided by height
>   (w/h, h/w) cannot exceed 3.0.

Your photo, http://www.hrgp.biz/Uploads/CompanyForTesting_499/NotesReminders/2608chemtec-logo.jpg, 250/65 = 3.84615384615 obviously exceed the maximum ratio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: body,
                            picture :'PICTURE_URL',
                            description : "DESCRIPTION"
                            }
                    , function (res) {
    if(!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
```

for more options check  - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed