# facebook og:image error image size must be 200px

Tags: facebook

i have put og:image tag on my website. but when i share link on facebook it goes good for images which are greater than 200px but for images less than 200px facebook gives error of minimum size.  How can we correctly share images which are less than 200px the minimum size of facebook??

Comment: have you specified the image:width & image:height also in meta tags?

Comment: You can't. It have to be over 200px

Answer (score 2):

It won't work properly . read more here at [facebook sharing best practises](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) . also read the discussion on this stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200312/what-is-the-minimum-width-and-height-of-facebook-open-graph-images).

> Small og:image: All the images referenced by og:image should be at
>   least 200px in both dimensions, with 1500x1500 preferred. (Maximum
>   image size is 5MB.) Please check all the images with tag og:image in
>   the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
>
> og:image should be larger: Provided og:image is not big enough. Please
>   use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500.
>   (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image ... will be used instead.